# How do i get the invoked operation name within a WCF Message Inspector

Tags: wcf, c#-3.0, operation, idispatchmessageinspector

I'm doing a  message inspector in WCF:

```
public class LogMessageInspector :
    IDispatchMessageInspector, IClientMessageInspector
```

which implements the method:

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request,
    IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
```

I can get the name of the invoked service with:

```
instanceContext.GetServiceInstance().GetType().Name
```

But how do I get the name of the invoked operation?

Answer (score 12):

It's not pretty, but this is what I did to get the operation name:

```
var action = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.Action;
var operationName = action.Substring(action.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) + 1);
```

Comment: `Operation.Current` is null in my case, it works if you retrieve the action through the Message object from the parameter as: `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request` ... `request.Headers.Action`.

Answer (score 8):

```
var operationName = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties["HttpOperationName"] as string;
```

Comment: Throws an `ArgumentException` for me

Answer (score 4):

This approach is similar to others presented here, but uses [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Path.GetFileName(OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.Action);
```

The return value of this method and the format of the `path` string work quite harmoniously in this scenario:

> The characters after the last directory character in path. If the last
>   character of path is a directory or volume separator character, this
>   method returns String.Empty. If path is null, this method returns
>   null.

Comment: Came up as an empty string for me, while Michael's answer worked.

Comment: @jk7: That is due to the fact that you are making RESTful requests (using `WebHttpBinding` of WCF). The solution above will work for SOAP requests (any standard bindings besides `WebHttpBinding`) while @Michael's solution will work for RESTful requests.

Comment: Related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852860/wcf-retrieving-methodinfo-from-operationcontext

Answer (score 2):

```
OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.Action.Split('/').ToList().Last();
```

Comment: The ToList() isn't necessary, is it?

Comment: @Nuzzolilo, Not Required.

Answer (score 1):

Little late to the party but I had to dig a little deeper than existing answers on this question because they seem to involve getting the action name and not the operation name. (Frequently they are the same so getting the action name does, in fact, get the operation name.)

Microsoft's Application Insights SDK Labs' WCF library makes [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-SDK-Labs/blob/ef72e14e3118c610dfbc79fcc0d7c2845b90c039/WCF/Shared/Implementation/WcfOperationContext.cs#L300) concerted effort:

```
private string DiscoverOperationName(OperationContext operationContext)
{
    var runtime = operationContext.EndpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime;
    string action = operationContext.IncomingMessageHeaders.Action;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(action))
    {
        foreach (var op in runtime.Operations)
        {
            if (op.Action == action)
            {
                return op.Name;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // WebHttpDispatchOperationSelector will stick the
        // selected operation name into a message property
        return this.GetWebHttpOperationName(operationContext);
    }

    var catchAll = runtime.UnhandledDispatchOperation;
    if (catchAll != null)
    {
        return catchAll.Name;
    }

    return "*";
}

private string GetWebHttpOperationName(OperationContext operationContext)
{
    var name = WebHttpDispatchOperationSelector.HttpOperationNamePropertyName;
    if (this.HasIncomingMessageProperty(name))
    {
        return this.GetIncomingMessageProperty(name) as string;
    }

    return "<unknown>";
}
```