# How to get the invoked operation name within a IClientMessageInspector?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, iclientmessageinspector

I implemented an [`IClientMessageInspector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms599812.aspx) to "intercept" outgoing web service call in my application. Is it possible to find out which operation is being called from inside the `BeforeSendRequest` and `AfterReceiveReply`?

There is a similar question here, [How do i get the invoked operation name within a WCF Message Inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477137/how-do-i-get-the-invoked-operation-name-within-a-wcf-message-inspector), which is for the server side (the side receiving the request). I tried to do something similar, e.g.

```
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        var v = OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties["HttpOperationName"];
        return null;
    }

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        var v = OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties["HttpOperationName"];
    }
```

but during outgoing request it seems that OperationContext.Current is null, so I cannot use this. Any idea how to get it? Any idea how to do it cleanly (as opposed, to say, parse the SOAP xml)?

Comment: This is hard because you are so low in the client stack that the information you need really is wrapped up in the message object. Any chance you could use a different inspector? For example an IParameterInspector is applied per operation and therefore is straight forward. It would also allow you to avoid binding specific solutions like HTTPOperationName.

Comment: how would Parameter inspector work?

Answer (score 5):

From the comments you asked how doing this could be done with [IParameterInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector.aspx). The operation name is part of the Before/AfterCall methods.

Just to add to my comments on which inspector to use. From [Carlos Figueira's blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/26/wcf-extensibility-iparameterinspector.aspx):

> The message inspectors, described in the previous post of this series,
>   allows you complete control over the message going through the WCF
>   stack. They’re very powerful, but you have to know how to deal with
>   the Message object, which is not the most desirable way of
>   programming. If the service model in WCF hides all the messaging
>   framework by allowing us to define our services in terms of
>   strongly-typed operations (i.e., using nice primitive and user defined
>   types), there should be a way of intercepting requests / responses
>   after all the processing to extract those parameters from incoming
>   messages (or before they’re packaged in outgoing messages) is done.
>   The IParameterInspector is exactly that – before and after each call,
>   the inspector gets a chance to inspect the operation inputs, outputs
>   and return value, in the same types as defined by the operation
>   contract, no conversion needed (the only thing needed is a cast, since
>   the parameters are passed as objects).

This is a complete command line program that demonstrates:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;

namespace WCFClientInspector
{
    public class OperationLogger : IParameterInspector
    {
        public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Completed operation:" + operationName);
        }

        public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calling operation:" + operationName);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class OperationLoggerEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            foreach (ClientOperation operation in clientRuntime.ClientOperations)
            {
                operation.ClientParameterInspectors.Add(new OperationLogger());
            }
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }
    }


    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISimple
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void DoSomthing(string s);
    }

    public class SimpleService : ISimple
    {
        public void DoSomthing(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called:" + s);
        }
    }

    public static class AttributesAndContext
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceHost simpleHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(SimpleService), new Uri("http://localhost/Simple"));
            simpleHost.Open();

            ChannelFactory<ISimple> factory = new ChannelFactory<ISimple>(simpleHost.Description.Endpoints[0]);
            factory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new OperationLoggerEndpointBehavior());
            ISimple proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

            proxy.DoSomthing("hi");

            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close the host.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            ((ICommunicationObject)proxy).Shutdown();

            simpleHost.Shutdown();
        }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        static public void Shutdown(this ICommunicationObject obj)
        {
            try
            {
                obj.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Shutdown exception: {0}", ex.Message);
                obj.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should give the output:

```
  Calling operation:DoSomthing 
  Called:hi 
  Completed operation:DoSomthing
  Press ENTER to close the host.
```

Answer (score 4):

What about `reply.Headers.Action` and `request.Headers.Action`. Of course the rest is same tricky as in question linked. So the full code will be:

```
var action = reply.Headers.Action.Substring(reply.Headers.Action.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) + 1);
```

or

```
var action = request.Headers.Action.Substring(request.Headers.Action.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) + 1);
```

Comment: weird.. when I test this code `request.Headers.Action` is an empty string `""` and `reply.Headers.Action` is null

Comment: most probably it is because at this stage, the operation to be executed is still not yet decided http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx#S2

Comment: The issue is that request.Headers.Action might not be specified. According to my understanding, this depends on the WSDL.