# How to write interceptor for WCF service

Tags: wcf, web-services, request

I have a WCF service with basicHttpBinding. I want to write interceptor for each method call in service to do some logging stuff.
I want to add this interceptor for some fields methods only.

I am pretty new in WCF. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to implement [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx) - you can [get the invoked method by looking at the OperationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477137/how-do-i-get-the-invoked-operation-name-within-a-wcf-message-inspector) and then you can decide whether you want to handle the method call.

You then have to implement the usual WCF plumbing, a ServiceBehavior and a BehaviorExtension, as in the doc page.