# Stop Application Insights including path parameters in the Operation Name

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

Our ASP.NET MVC application includes some URI path parameters, like:

> https://example.com/api/query/14hes1017ceimgS2ESsIec

In Application Insights, this URI above becomes *Operation Name*

```
GET /api/query/14hes1017ceimgS2ESsIec
```

We don't want millions of unique Operations like this; it's just one code method serving them all (see below). We want to roll them up under an Operation Name like

```
GET /api/query/{path}
```

---

Here is the code method - I think App Insights could detect that the URI contains a query parameter... but it doesn't.

```
    [Route("api/query/{hash}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string hash)
    {
        ...
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482869/wcf-service-operation-name

Comment: Sure does @PavelChuchuva :) specifically the HttpContextExtension.GetRequestTelemetry... I have wanted that before...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason Application Insights does not detect that the suffix of your Operation Name is a parameter is because the SDK does not look at your code, and for all practical purposes that's a valid URI.
Two options to get what you want:

1. Change your API to pass the parameter in the query string (that is stripped out of the Operation Name)
2. Implement your own `ITelemetryProcessor` (detailed explanation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling)), and remove the suffix hash from the Operation Name yourself

Answer (score 3):

MS are working on this feature with https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/176

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution for ASP.NET using Minimal API's. This will use the routePattern from the Endpoint as the name and operation_Name.

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

namespace Web.ApplicationInsights;

public class UseRoutePatternAsNameTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public UseRoutePatternAsNameTelemetryInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        if (telemetry is RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry && httpContext != null)
        {
            var endpoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint();
            if (endpoint is RouteEndpoint routeEndpoint)
            {
                var telemetryName = CreateTelemetryName(routeEndpoint, httpContext);
                requestTelemetry.Name = telemetryName;
                requestTelemetry.Context.Operation.Name = telemetryName;
            }
        }
    }
    
    private static string CreateTelemetryName(RouteEndpoint routeEndpoint, HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var routePattern = routeEndpoint.RoutePattern.RawText ?? "";
        var routeName = routePattern.StartsWith("/") ? routePattern : $"/{routePattern}";
        var telemetryName = $"{httpContext.Request.Method} {routeName}";
        return telemetryName;
    }
}
```

And the following in Program.cs

```
AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(builder);

static void AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(WebApplicationBuilder webApplicationBuilder)
{
    webApplicationBuilder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
    webApplicationBuilder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    webApplicationBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, UseRoutePatternAsNameTelemetryInitializer>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I hacked it with this hardcoded `OperationNameMunger` (using [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling#add-properties) for inspiration).

I wired it into the `ApplicationInsights.config`, straight after the `OperationNameTelemetryInitializer`.

---

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

namespace My.Namespace
{
    public class OperationNameMunger : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            var existingOpName = telemetry.Context?.Operation?.Name;
            if (existingOpName == null)
                return;

            const string matchesInterestingOps = "^([A-Z]+ /api/query/)[^ ]+$";
            var match = Regex.Match(existingOpName, matchesInterestingOps);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                telemetry.Context.Operation.Name = match.Groups[1].Value + "{hash}";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into this I felt like it would be more useful to have the actual text of the route as the operation name, rather than try to identify all the different ways an ID could be constructed.

The problem is that route template exists down the tree from `HttpRequestMessage`, but in a `TelemetryInitializer` you end up with only access to `HttpContext.Current.Request` which is an `HttpRequest`.

They don't make it easy but this code works:

```cs
    // This class runs at the start of each request and gets the name of the
    // route template from actionContext.ControllerContext?.RouteData?.Route?.RouteTemplate
    // then stores it in HttpContext.Current.Items
    public class AiRewriteUrlsFilter : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        internal const string AiTelemetryName = "AiTelemetryName";
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            string method = actionContext.Request?.Method?.Method;
            string routeData = actionContext.ControllerContext?.RouteData?.Route?.RouteTemplate;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(routeData) && routeData.StartsWith("api/1.0/") && HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(AiTelemetryName, $"{method} /{routeData}");
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
    }

    // This class runs when the telemetry is initialized and pulls
    // the value we set in HttpContext.Current.Items and uses it
    // as the new name of the telemetry.
    public class AiRewriteUrlsInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            if (telemetry is RequestTelemetry rTelemetry && HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                string telemetryName = HttpContext.Current.Items[AiRewriteUrlsFilter.AiTelemetryName] as string;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(telemetryName))
                {
                    rTelemetry.Name = telemetryName;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @Mike's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69168857/134761).

- Updated for ASP.NET Core 5/6
- Uses route name, if specified.
- Uses template and API version, if route data is available.

Telemetry name before/after:
`GET /chat/ba1ce6bb-01e8-4633-918b-08d9a363a631/since/2021-11-18T18:51:08`
`GET /chat/{id}/since/{timestamp}`

https://gist.github.com/angularsen/551bcbc5f770d85ff9c4dfbab4465546

The solution consists of:

- Global MVC action filter, to compute telemetry name from route data.
- ITelemetryInitializer to update the telemetry name.
- Configure filter and initializer in ASP.NET's Startup class

**Global filter to compute the telemetry name from the API action route data.**

```
#nullable enable
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace Digma.Api.Common.Telemetry
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Action filter to construct a simpler telemetry name from the route name or the route template.
    /// <br/><br/>
    /// Out of the box, Application Insights sometimes uses request telemetry names like "GET /chat/ba1ce6bb-01e8-4633-918b-08d9a363a631/since/2021-11-18T18:51:08".
    /// This makes it hard to see how many requests were for a particular API action.
    /// This is a <a href="https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1418">known issue</a>.
    /// <br/><br/>
    /// - If route name is defined, then use that.<br/>
    /// - If route template is defined, then the name is formatted as "{method} /{template} v{version}".
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// - <b>"MyCustomName"</b> if route name is explicitly defined with <c>[Route("my_path", Name="MyCustomName")]</c><br/>
    /// - <b>"GET /config v2.0"</b> if template is "config" and API version is 2.0.<br/>
    /// - <b>"GET /config"</b> if no API version is defined.
    /// </example>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The value is passed on via <see cref="HttpContext.Items"/> with the key <see cref="SimpleRequestTelemetryNameInitializer.TelemetryNameKey"/>.
    /// </remarks>
    public class SimpleRequestTelemetryNameActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var httpContext = context.HttpContext;
            var attributeRouteInfo = context.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo;

            if (attributeRouteInfo?.Name is { } name)
            {
                // If route name is defined, it takes precedence.
                httpContext.Items.Add(SimpleRequestTelemetryNameInitializer.TelemetryNameKey, name);
            }
            else if (attributeRouteInfo?.Template is { } template)
            {
                // Otherwise, use the route template if defined.
                string method = httpContext.Request.Method;
                string versionSuffix = GetVersionSuffix(httpContext);

                httpContext.Items.Add(SimpleRequestTelemetryNameInitializer.TelemetryNameKey, $"{method} /{template}{versionSuffix}");
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }

        private static string GetVersionSuffix(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            try
            {
                var requestedApiVersion = httpContext.GetRequestedApiVersion()?.ToString();

                // Add leading whitespace so we can simply append version string to telemetry name.
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestedApiVersion))
                    return $" v{requestedApiVersion}";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Some requests lack the IApiVersioningFeature, like requests to get swagger doc
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

**Telemetry initializer that updates the name of `RequestTelemetry`.**

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Digma.Api.Common.Telemetry
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Changes the name of request telemetry to the value assigned by <see cref="SimpleRequestTelemetryNameActionFilter"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The value is passed on via <see cref="HttpContext.Items"/> with the key <see cref="TelemetryNameKey"/>.
    /// </remarks>
    public class SimpleRequestTelemetryNameInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        internal const string TelemetryNameKey = "SimpleOperationNameInitializer:TelemetryName";
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public SimpleRequestTelemetryNameInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            if (telemetry is RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry && httpContext != null)
            {
                if (httpContext.Items.TryGetValue(TelemetryNameKey, out var telemetryNameObj)
                    && telemetryNameObj is string telemetryName
                    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(telemetryName))
                {
                    requestTelemetry.Name = telemetryName;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ASP.NET startup class to configure the global filter and telemetry initializer.**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Register telemetry initializer.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
        services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, SimpleRequestTelemetryNameInitializer>();

        services.AddMvc(opt =>
        {
            // Global MVC filters.
            opt.Filters.Add<SimpleRequestTelemetryNameActionFilter>();
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // ...other configuration
    }
}
```

Comment: As a reminder to all: make sure that you are not loading the extension in app services because it will disable the SDK (and by extension the changes you made. Yes, of course the pun was intended).

Comment: I assume you mean Azure App Service? If so yes, I believe it does.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "make sure that you are not loading the extension in app services because it will disable the SDK" ?

Comment: In Azure App Services, if you enable the AppInsights extension (under the Application Insights blade), it will disable the SDK and therefore any manual tracking you're doing in code using the SDK. There was a preview to have them work side-by-side, but I haven't seen it recently.

Comment: For WebAPI (and probably also MVC) you just can skip the ActionFilter and just use `(RouteEndpoint)httpContext.GetEndpoint()).RoutePattern.ToString()` [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.endpointhttpcontextextensions.getendpoint?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: @Staeff this does indeed work a lot better (easier). But not ToString() - that'll give you "" sometimes. RawString (rawtext?) works all of the time. You might want to also include the method to keep the pattern the same. Good find.