# Generic Logging Method Name and User In WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, logging

For every WCF method, I need to have a log message right after the method is called, and another log message after the method ends. For example, the code may look like this:

```
public string Method1() 
{ 
  try {
    Log("Method1 start"); 
    /*implementation is here*/ 
  } 
  finally 
  { 
   Log("Method1 end");
  } 
}
```

The two logs need to contain the WCF method name. Now I need to add this to all WCF methods. Is it possible that I can create a generic method to do this, so that I do not need to repeat writing this on every WCF call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called Aspect Oriented Programming.

AOP comes in different flavors and handles cross-cutting concerns like logging.

- WCF Interception (see @Gilad answer)
- IoC Interception (is a bit tricky to get to work with WCF, see more [here](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/introducing-unity.wcf-providing-easy-ioc-integration-for-your-wcf-services))
- PostSharp

PostSharp is a very nice tool that implements AOP on build time, whereas WCF and IoC interception is done runtime. But the general idea is the same.
See more [Here](https://www.postsharp.net/diagnostics/net-logging).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `Interceptors`. WCF enables you to add interceptors in different stages of the request processing.

Implement an interceptor that will look like your example.
For information about the [interceptors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744842(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

I'd recomment that your interceptor function will look something like this:
*To get the method name look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477137/how-do-i-get-the-invoked-operation-name-within-a-wcf-message-inspector)*

```
{
    try
    {
        Log(string.Format("Entering method: {0}",/*function name*/));
        //proceed with execution
        Log(string.Format("Exiting method: {0}",/*function name*/));
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Log(string.Format("Exiting method {0} with failure: {1}:,/*function name*/,exception.ToString());
}
```

---

- What I also normally do is in the `Entering` message print values on input parameters if there are any, and also on `Exiting` in the case of a return value print it too. Makes log reading so much more usful.