# C# WCF - Find Name of endpoint that was called

Tags: c#, wcf, authorization

How do I find out the endpoint that was called for my WCF service within the authorisation manager?

Current Code:

```
 public class AuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
      Log(operationContext.EndpointDispatcher.ContractName);
      Log(operationContext.EndpointDispatcher.EndpointAddress);
      Log(operationContext.EndpointDispatcher.AddressFilter);
      //return true if the endpoint = "getDate";
     }
}
```

I want the endpoint that was called, but the results are currently:

MYWCFSERVICE

https://myurl.co.uk/mywcfservice.svc
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.PrefixEndpointAddressMessageFilter

What I need is the part after the .svc eg/ 
https://myurl.co.uk/mywcfservice.svc/testConnection?param1=1

In this scenario I want "testConnection" to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477137/how-do-i-get-the-invoked-operation-name-within-a-wcf-message-inspector) answer.

```
public class AuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        var action = operationContext.IncomingMessageHeaders.Action;

        // Fetch the operationName based on action.
        var operationName = action.Substring(action.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) + 1);

        // Remove everything after ?
        int index = operationName.IndexOf("?");
        if (index > 0)
            operationName = operationName.Substring(0, index);

        return operationName.Equals("getDate", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, got the action via the operationContext:
operationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.To.ToString()

Comment: Cool. Then you should post your own answer to enlighten future readers. :)

Comment: I've added it as a separate function as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Smoksness! Sent me in the correct direction.

I've made a function that returns the action called:

```
private String GetEndPointCalled(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        string urlCalled = operationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.To.ToString();
        int startIndex = urlCalled.IndexOf(".svc/") + 5;
        if (urlCalled.IndexOf('?') == -1)
        {
            return urlCalled.Substring(startIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            int endIndex = urlCalled.IndexOf('?');
            int length = endIndex - startIndex;
            return urlCalled.Substring(startIndex, length);
        }
    }
```