# WCF: Distinguish between REST and SOAP requests using the OperationContext

Tags: wcf, rest, soap, operationcontext

In WCF security, given the current OperationContext, what is the best way to determine whether the request is a SOAP request or a REST request?

Answer (score 10):

You could look at the binding name on the ChannelDispatcher:

```
string bindingName = OperationContext.Current
                        .EndpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.BindingName;
```

For REST, it would be `webHttpBinding` - anything else would be SOAP.